# DT package Color the background of the cells according to a double conditionality

Tags: r, cell, dt

I have a problem to finish my DT on R. The colors appear according to ranges of values. For the DD column, when the value is between -3 and +3, the cell is orange. However, I would like when the values ​​of D and DD are 0, the cell in DD appears dark green, not orange.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tip4i.jpg)

Here is my script :

```
#color cells
datatable(data = t,rownames = F, filter = 'top',extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
  dom = 'Bfrtip',
  pageLength=20,
  buttons = c('copy', 'excel', 'pdf'))) %>%
  formatStyle('EE',
              backgroundColor=styleInterval(cuts=c(250,500,750,1000,1500),
                                            values=c('darkgreen','lightgreen','yellow','orange','pink','red')))%>%
  formatStyle('PJFA',
              backgroundColor=styleInterval(cuts=c(3.9,5.1),values=c('red','orange','darkgreen'))) %>%
  formatStyle('DEE',
              backgroundColor=styleInterval(cuts=c(-201,201),values=c('darkgreen','orange','red')))%>%
    formatStyle('DPJFN',
                backgroundColor=styleInterval(cuts=c(-0.6,0,0.6),values=c('red','orange','lightgreen','darkgreen')))%>%
  formatStyle('DPJFA',
              backgroundColor=styleInterval(cuts=c(-0.6,0,0.6),values=c('red','orange','lightgreen','darkgreen'))) %>%
  formatStyle('DD',
              backgroundColor=styleInterval(cuts=c(-5,-3,3,5),values=c('darkgreen','lightgreen','orange','pink','red'))) %>%
  formatStyle('DPJFN','Chgt_poste',
              color = styleEqual(c('y','n'),values=c('white','black'))) %>%
  formatStyle('NFR',
              backgroundColor=styleInterval(cuts=c(1,3,5,7,8),values=c('darkred','red','pink','orange','lightgreen','darkgreen'))) %>%
  formatStyle('NFJ',
              backgroundColor=styleInterval(cuts=c(7,8,9,10,12),values=c('red','pink','orange','yellow','lightgreen','darkgreen'))) %>%
  formatStyle('D',
              backgroundColor=styleInterval(cuts=c(0.1,3,6,9,12),values=c('darkgreen','lightgreen','yellow','orange','pink','red')))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `styleInterval` followed by `styleEqual`:

```
library(DT)
dat <- data.frame(
  CC = c(7, 4, 6, 9, 2),
  DD = c(-6, -4, -2, 0, 4)
)

datatable(
  dat
) %>%
  formatStyle(
    "DD",
    backgroundColor = styleInterval(
      cuts = c(-5, -3, 3, 5), 
      values = c('darkgreen', 'lightgreen', 'orange', 'pink', 'red')
    )
  ) %>%
  formatStyle(
    "DD",
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(0, "blue")
  )
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

Following the comment, you have to do an hidden auxiliary column:

```
library(DT)
dat <- data.frame(
  CC = c(7, 4, 6, 9, 2),
  DD = c(-6, -4, -2, 0, 4),
  D  = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 3)
)
dat$hidden <- dat$DD == 0 & dat$D == 0

datatable(
  dat,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = 4, visible = FALSE)
    )
  )
) %>%
  formatStyle(
    "DD",
    backgroundColor = styleInterval(
      cuts = c(-5, -3, 3, 5), 
      values = c('darkgreen', 'lightgreen', 'orange', 'pink', 'red')
    )
  ) %>%
  formatStyle(
    "DD", "hidden",
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(TRUE, "blue")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my problem is that I want cell DD=0 to be colored green only if cell D=0. With your solution it doesn't work.

Comment: @AntoineW OK. See my edit.

Comment: It's works, thank's a lot